# Как убрать из массива повторяющиеся элемент?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Например, массив состоит из таких значений: `2, 3, 3, 4`.

Как сделать так, чтобы после обработки массив состоял из `2, 3, 4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить максимально неоптимальное решение: если массив не отсортирован, то отсортируй. Заводим Дальше колдуем над отсортированным массивом. Создаем цикл, в котором проверяем данную и последующую переменную массива. Если они равны, то теперь нужен какой-нибудь цикл, который через перемену мест значений массива сдвинет все влево.
Либо же заводите новый массив, равный по длине исходному, заполняем его условно -1 (допустим, что все числа положительны), в который будем записывать числа. И если какой-то элемент массива равен элементу предыдущего, то мы его не записываем. А потом выводим новый массив, пока его значение не стало равно -1... Вот... А если все же нужно и с отрицательными, то это уже по-другому надо сделать. У меня возник в голове способ сделать это через структуру стэк, но вдруг вам это покажется сложным. Вообщем, алгоритм примерно такой, если просто:

1. сортируем массив
2. цикл for от 1 до его длины (задаем еще один массив, в который уже вписываем 0ой элемент первого массива)
3. если переменная не равна предыдущей, то записываем ее в новый массив.
   если переменная равна предыдущей, то пропускаем ее
4. выводим массив

должно сработать наверное... код самому писать сейчас ленива))

Comment: Звучит как хороший план, спасибо!

Comment: если все же нужно реализовать с отрицательными значениями, то могу через стек прописать данное дело

Comment: Пожалуй, не надо , этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Но можно и без нового массива, т.е. ничто не мешает переписывать новое (еще не повторяющееся) значение в тот же массив

Comment: в принципе да. Не додумался... в час ночи плохо думаю

Answer (score 2):

Это же С++!

```
int a[] = { 2, 3, 3, 4 };

sort(begin(a),end(a));
int n = distance(begin(a),unique(begin(a),end(a)));
```

После этого в `n` - количество разных элементов в массиве (элементы `a[0] ... a[n-1]`) - по сути, новый размер массива (вернее, интересующей вас части).

Можно и так:

```
int a[] = { 2, 3, 3, 4 };
int n = size(a);

sort(a,a+n);
n = unique(a,a+n) - a;
```

С вектором -

```
vector<int> a { 2, 3, 3, 4 };

sort(a.begin(),a.end());
a.erase(unique(a.begin(),a.end()),a.end());
```

Если нужно просто вывести, например, а не расположить "на месте", без дополнительной памяти - то можно использовать `set`:

```
set<int> s;
copy(begin(a),end(a),inserter(s,s.begin()));
for(int i : s) cout << i << " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет такой идеи?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 7;
    int arr[SIZE] = { 2,2,5,7,1,3,3};
    int* new_arr = nullptr;

    list<int> my(arr, arr + SIZE);
    my.unique();
    int new_sizez = my.size();


    new_arr = new int[new_sizez];

    for (auto i = 0; i < new_sizez; i++)
    {
        new_arr[i] = my.front();
        my.pop_front();
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_sizez; i++)
    {
        cout << new_arr[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```